# Using XML-Stylesheets Without Losing Default Browser Functionality

Tags: css, xml

The default view of XML files in many browsers is a nestled layout with collapsible sections. However, the moment I add a stylesheet to the xml document (even if just a blank file) the whole style of the document gets redone and the menus are no longer collapsible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xml.css"?>
...
```

Is there a way to make minor adjustments to the style (for example just making a section bold) without losing all default style and functionality?

Comment: Don't it depends on browser implementation?

Comment: CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. This implies it is possible to load several CSS. Try to load a second stylesheet where you specifically add the property `{ font-weight: bold; }` to the nodes you want. If it doesn't work, try the same with `{ font-weight: bold !important; }`.